# Circuit Analysis: Capacitor voltage surge

Tags: voltage, capacitor, resistors, diodes

I am new to electronics and I am experimenting with falstad circuit simulator to understand how capacitors work with different components. In the below circuit, when the switch is open , the capacitor gets charged to full 10V and voltage across the 10K resistor drops to 0V. This makes sense. But when I close the switch(2nd picture), I see an immediate surge of voltage(of 18V) around 10k resistor and a negative voltage around the capacitor. What exactly is this behavior? Now after a while, the capacitor is discharged to the forward voltage of the diode(~5mV) as shown in 3rd picture since they are in parallel. I am under the assumption when the switch is closed the capacitor should start discharging via diode normally like any other component(like resistor).

[falstad circuit link](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWEB2WZIICxgEwGZMA2QgDmRMJAUipEzyoFMBaMMAKAHdxCa9SeNbJUhdBIHAkpheIPJExQxMmmEyKV4ZCPYBzccIMkaJ9gCVxhDbLw4o9zKpP2YCdgCdL11evvplNgri-CRKAA50ocaR4L4MptyYoWresYqiiVGqslZKAM5yQWAAnHbyijiOLiAAZgCGADZ5jGLlWpRtJXYZhRVVbTgkoaL6bXgkim1Jzj1jCGVB4%20kevSDRnYN%208D2auW25s0F7QdGiAMbiKatXJrDwEMww6oQ4avO2CMUIbAhIMHAcbgbUKdXw7WRgbTiSQ6CIhEB7AS4EEuVoCY6KA5o5KbUHLIFFOJFKGiCKDUI4SDJUoSKlyVHcLq05IQsFicnM65siKOGgc3lyeb0hJ0OASIarDk9AV4IVzbrsAAmkol8okIEVjHqAFcGgAXdhAA)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try setting a realistic resistance for the switch, and make sure the timestep is less than the corresponding RC time constant.

Comment: It's a simulator. You don't know how it works so you don't know how it reacts to extreme corner cases, where for example dv/dt is infinite. You also don't say which type of capacitor simulation model you have selected in Falstad, there's at least two of them.

Comment: @Justme, you are correct after unchecking the "Trapezoidal Approximation" on the capacitor the above behavior is gone.